# Actionscript3, Adobe Air for mobile: Alternative for bordercontainer?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I am using adobe air to create a mobile application. I want to dynamically add a container or group that can contain some elements, and has a border and a background color. Since these are added dynamically, I use Actionscript 3. A bordercontainer works fine, however according to: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/BorderContainer.html this component is not meant to be used for mobile.

So my queston is: **What lightweight component can contain other elements, and has a settable background color and border?**

Answer (score 1):

Try simply using the Group spark component.  You would add a Rect with a filled background and a solid line:

```
<s:Group>
  <s:Rect>
     <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke />
     </s:stroke>
     <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor />
     </s:fill>
  </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```

For an additional performance enhancement,  you might want to look at FXG precompilation.  Some article about that [here](http://soenkerohde.com/2010/12/compile-time-fxg/).